# Bluefish does not start any longer

Tags: css, widget, gtk, fallback, bluefish

I was working on a webpage with multiple windows of bluefish opened. I needed to reorganize my folders, so i thought that it would be easier to just close bluefish completely and then load all files freshly.

After closing it down it wont start any longer. When running in terminal the following error is printed out:

```
** (bluefish:2966): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: Die Ressource auf »/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css« existiert nicht

** (bluefish:2966): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: Die Ressource auf »/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css« existiert nicht

(bluefish:2966): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:997:2: Missing name of pseudo-class

(bluefish:2966): GLib-ERROR **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.40.2/./glib/gmem.c:103: failed to allocate 18446744073663932802 bytes
Trace/Breakpoint ausgelöst (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Rebooting didnt help either.

I was not able to find help by google.

If somebody has the same problem, i recommend using Atom, which seems like an (maybe even better) alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues with bluefish crash using Ubuntu then please try to run the below command from terminal, I hope your problem will resolved

rm -r ~/.bluefish

Answer (score 0):

Erasing the ~/.bluefish directory did the trick for me.